# Error Deploying Bacpac on Azure SQL Database when the database has Azure AD Users

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms, bacpac

I'm trying to deploy a `.bacpac` to my Azure Subscription, the database has some Azure AD users. I can generate the `.bacpac` with SSMS, but when I deploy the replicated database on Azure, I'm getting this error:

> Could not import package.
>
> Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider:
>
> Msg 15419, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Supplied parameter sid should be binary(16).
>
> Error SQL72045: Script execution error. The executed script:
> CREATE USER [ADUser]
> WITH SID = <ID>, TYPE = E;
>
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

**Question:** how can I deploy the `.bacpac` if my database has users from Azure AD?

I did some test to avoid this error and I can deploy a `.bacpac` file with SQL Server users, the problem only appears when the database has Azure users.

Comment: Have you tried what is says in the [CREATE USER documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql)? e.g.: `CREATE USER [bob@contoso.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;`

Comment: Yes, It works but I don't want the Azure AD Users in the objective database, I want this users only in the source database, I found a solution using SQLPackage, I'm going to share the commands in the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed with **@AlwaysLearning** , as per this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

> Creating user with SID is only applies to users with passwords (SQL Server authentication) in a contained database.

also, you can see in below error we cand use SID with the external provider it is only applicable to SQL user with password.

[image]

you can use below command to create external user in your database.

```sql
CREATE USER [username@domain.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

And then try to deploy the database in azure SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with [@pratik-lad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18043699/pratik-lad) and [@AlwaysLearning](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390122/alwayslearning), add the user login and then you can deploy `.bacpac` file, but in my case I don't want the Azure Users in the new database so I made a script using [SQL Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver16) for this.

First extract `.dacpac` file with the flag `/p:ExtractAllTableData=True`

```
sqlpackage /Action:extract /p:IgnorePermissions=true /SourceConnectionString:"Data Source=Connection String" /TargetFile:"target.dacpac" /p:ExtractAllTableData=True
```

Then you can publish the database with this flag `ExcludeObjectTypes="Users;Logins;RoleMembership;Permissions;DatabaseRoles"`

```
sqlpackage /a:publish /tcs:"Data Source=Connection String" /sf:"./target.dacpac" /p:DatabaseEdition=Basic /p:DropObjectsNotInSource=True /p:ExcludeObjectTypes="Users;Logins;RoleMembership;Permissions;DatabaseRoles"
```